# what gem/method to use to generate PDF's from static hosted pages using thoughtbot high-voltage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a static set of help pages that I serve in a Rails 3.2 application using Thoughbots high-voltage gem. I'm just using this in a 'vanilla' way, without serving up the html pages via the controller.

*Background*

I had originally tried to do this myself adapting Michael Hartl's tutorial around static pages - i.e I have a set of static pages with their own controller, and I was trying to create a sub-directory under the static pages view, but could not get my routing to work, so Google searches revealed Thoughbots High-Voltage gem.

***Aspiration***

What I would like is a recommendation of what gem or method is best to generated PDF files using Thoughtbots High-Voltage gem.

Has anybody done this?

I want to be able to host this on heroku so if there are any `gotacha's` I'd like to know about these up front.

My current implementation is a basic Rails 3.2 application with the High-Voltage gem installed and a number of views under the pages sub-directory.

- pages/help/users
- pages/help/products
- pages/help/orders

I have images within my html pages, not sure if this causes complications.

***EDIT:*** Added controller based on answer provided as still having issues with wicked_pdf on Rails 3.2.3, ruby 1.9.3-p125 on Lion

```
class PagesController < HighVoltage::PagesController
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      super
    end
    format.pdf do
      #render :pdf => "pdf_file" # wicked_pdf syntax here
      render :pdf => :id,
             :layout => 'application',
             #:template => 'help/products/product_tolerance.html.erb',
             :template => 'pages/#{:id}.html.erb',
             :show_as_html => params[:debug],
             :footer => {
                :left => "Generated on @now",
                :centre => "Centre",
                :right => "Page # of page(s)"
             }        
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Routes file contains:

`match "/pages/*id" => 'pages#show', :as => :page, :via => :get, :format => false`

Should the :format be true? In the controller and in high_voltage?

Comment: Thanks just realised when looking at another question. Apologies if I seemed rude or ignorant. This is an awesome forum and I desperately need help at times after googling sometimes what feels like for hours to solve something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the High Voltage pages controller as described here:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage#override

Then install either [pdfkit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/) or [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) (html to pdf converters)
and hook them into that controller to create PDF versions:

```
class PagesController < HighVoltage::PagesController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        super
      end
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "pdf_file" # wicked_pdf syntax here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Unixmonkey. Currently cannot get the override to run.
Have `match "/pages/*id" => 'pages#show', :as => :page , :via => :get, :format => false` in routes file and get following error:
`No such page: help/products/index`
The url is `http://localhost:3009/pages/help/products/index`

Comment: The url is `http://localhost:3009/pages/help/products/index`

Working on this for 2 days. Reverted to manually creating pages without thoughbot gem, ran into problems with wicked_pdf (not creating images). Rails 3.2.3, ruby 1.9.3. wkhtmltopdf @cmd line renders entire page. Can simply call this cmd from within rails app via a script, but my knowledge is limited at present.

Comment: Oh what does the `super` do? It now renders the html.erb files which it wasn't before. Super isn't in the example on the thoughbot site. Was that an error?
Now I am getting the routing error when I try to run the pdf with the following link:
`<li><%= link_to "Product Tolerances", page_path("help/products/product_tolerances") %><%= link_to "Create/Download as PDF", page_path("help/products/product_tolerances", :format => :pdf) %> </li>`

When I looked into wicked_pdf and high_voltage gems in my rvm folder, I figured based on my current understanding that high_voltage only supports html

Comment: @user1149642 `super` calls what the original show method in HighVoltage::PagesController does (https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/blob/master/app/controllers/high_voltage/pages_controller.rb). I think taking `:format => false` out of your route will let you use the format key, and the images not showing is due to how wkhtmltopdf works. Use the `wicked_pdf_image_tag` helper as directed in the readme.

Comment: now get a rendering issue having removed the `:format` statement. (Had tried this but also took away the `:via => :get`.
Now have : `No such page: help/products/product_tolerance`
Rake routes looks correct. Url is `localhost:3009/pages/help/products/product_tolerance?format=pdf`
If I change to `:template => '#{:id}.html.erb` I get a missing template message `Missing template /#{:id}.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/railsdev/Development/railsprojects/Learning/thoughtbot/inc_high_voltage/app/views" `

Comment: Is it related to the following in the high_voltage gems config routes?
`Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match "/#{HighVoltage::content_path}*id" => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :as => :page, :format => false

end`

As per the pervious change does one need to override this? If so just by editing my own copy? New to all this. I did post an 'issue' at the gem github page

Comment: Went back and started from scratch today, after having built my own version of high_voltage within my app (so not as a gem). I thought having learnt from that I could approach this problem again. It worked as highlighted by Unixmonkey. Thanks